# Return full value of a property

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm trying to get the Program IDs of DCOM applications but when returning the value of the property, it doesn't give the full contents.

```
$a = Get-ChildItem 'registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\' -Recurse | Where-Object Name -match 'ProgID'
```

This returns all applications that contain a ProgID

```
    Hive: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{000C1090-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}


Name                           Property
----                           --------
ProgId                         (default) : WindowsInstaller.Installer
```

When trying to get the property value in the example, "WindowsInstaller.Installer"
via `$a.Property`

returns

`(default)`

How do I return the full property contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `Get-ChildItem` returns for registry locations are [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey) instances representing registry *keys*.

To get the data for the *unnamed* default *value* of each such key - which contains the ProgID of interest - you can use the `.GetValue()` method with the *empty string* (`''`).

Note that PowerShell represents the unnamed default value differently, as `'(default)'`, as shown in your question.

```
Get-ChildItem registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID -Recurse | 
  Where-Object Name -match ProgID |
    ForEach GetValue ''
```

As an aside: the `Name` property of registry `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]` instances contains the full key *path*, so a better way to limit matching to just a key's *name* is to use
`Where-Object Name -match '\\ProgID$` in your case.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you, I did not know what (default) meant but I do now!